# How to check VPN server adress of vpn I'm connected to?

Tags: networking, internet, vpn, openvpn

I'm using Open VPN I'm connected to VPN and I'm trying to make a kill-switch following advices found here on askubuntu.com but I don't know the ip of my vpn. 
Could you tell me how can I check it / which command in the terminal I should type etc?

Thank you